# for a function in .net 4

Tags: asp.net, performance, .net-4.0, outputcache, asp.net-4.0

I read at [Scottgu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) blog about using OutputCache for a function but this didn't worked for me. How can I use [OutputCache(Duration=60)] for a function and can I add VaryByParam in this statement? Which namespace is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OutputCacheAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) class is part of the [System.Web.MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.aspx) namespace. You *can* use VaryByParam with it:

```
<OutputCache(Duration:=60, VaryByParam:="Any")> _
Function Index() As ActionResult
    ViewData("Message") = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!"

    Return View()
End Function
```

but I would guess that you can only apply it to MVC methods that return an ActionResult - I don't think you could use it in a WebForms project (which I'm guessing from your question is what you're using).

Comment: @PhilPursglove 80% you're right. But this would be a very useful property for .net :(